# Simplest solution for differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the simplest solution:

$y' + 2y = z' + 2z$ I think proper notation is not sure, y' means first derivate of y. ($\frac{dy}{dt}+ 2y = \frac{dz}{dt} + 2z$)

$y(0)=1$

I got kind of confused, is $y=z=1$ a proper solution here? Or is disqualified because a constant is not reliant on time and something like $e^t$ is the simplest solution?

You can choose z and y however you like.

Comment: There really isn't a simplest solution.  This is true as long as y(t) = z(t) + C.

Comment: ^ $z $ and $y $ are satisfied when $z=y $, you can't add a constant because of the terms $2y $ and $2z $.

Comment: but if y' +2y = z' +2z, then the solution has to be y=z right? but I am not sure which values they can take

Comment: Are you sure the question wasn't to find the most general solution?

Comment: not general solution, any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w(t)=y(t)-z(t)$.  Then, we have

$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}+2y(t)=\frac{dz(t)}{dt}+2z(t)\implies \frac{dw(t)}{dt}+2w(t)=0$$

Hence, $w(t)=Ae^{-2t}$ for some constant $A$, from which we find that $y(t)=z(t)+Ae^{-2t}$ .  Using the initial condition, $y(0)=1$, we obtain

$$y(t)=z(t)+(1-z(0))e^{-2t} \tag 1$$

and we are done!

---

> **EDIT:**
>
> It appears that the OP would like the "simplest" functions $y(t)$ and $z(t)$ that satisfy $(1)$.  Choosing $y(t)=z(t)=1$ satisfies $(1)$ and provides the "simplest" functions that do so.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to have y = e^t and z = e^t?

Comment: This is the most general solution. That isn't what was requested, but it may well be what was wanted.

Comment: nope, can choose any specific z and y, only criteria was to be the simplest.

Comment: @Kameegaming If one can choose $y$ and $z$, simply take $y=z=1$.  That is "simple."

Comment: I guess thats the solution then

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dy}{dt}+ 2y = \frac{dz}{dt} + 2z$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}-\frac{dz}{dt}=-2(y-z)$$
$$\frac{d(y-z)}{dt}=-2(y-z)$$
$$\frac{d(y-z)}{(y-z)}=-2dt$$

Integrating both sides, we get
$$\ln|y-z|=-2t+c$$ where $c$ is a constant of integration.

Using the given condition, we have
$$\ln|1-z(0)|=c$$

So we have that $$\ln|y-z|=\ln|1-z(0)|-2t$$ Or even better, we have that
$$\ln\left|\frac{y-z}{1-z(0)}\right|=-2t$$

Thus we have that $$y(t)=z(t)+[1-z(0)]e^{-2t}$$

That's the simplest solution possible.

Comment: this is not simple, you can choose z and y however you like, to get the simple answeo

Answer (score 0):

The answer you propose certainly can't be faulted.

There is not a unique accepted criterion of "simplest" in mathematics. Certainly we expect people to agree in many specific cases. Many items in high stakes tests are of the form "find the next term in the sequence" but what is the simplest sequence starting $1,2,4,..?$ We reasonably expect most people to say "powers of $2$ so $1,2,4,8,16,...$" But maybe the differences should be $1,2,3,4,..$ so the quadratic fit $1,2,4,7,11,...$ is simpler?

Certainly one criterion is "a polynomial if possible and, if so, one of lowest degree." That would give $1,2,4,7,11,...$

Consider the differential equation $w'(t)=-2w(t).$ The most general solution is $w=ke^{-2t}$ where $k=w(0)$. Any initial condition uniquely specifies a solution. If I denied you any initial condition and asked for the simplest answer, most people might say $w(t)=e^{-2t}$ though the criterion above prefers $w(t)=0.$ The other might qualify as the simplest non-trivial solution. All these are strictly positive or strictly negative. The general positive solution is $e^{-2t+C}$ and $C=0$ seems simplest.

Your problem could be cast as

> $y(t)$ and $z(t)$ are functions such that $y(0)=1$ and $w(t)=z(t)-y(t)$ satisfies $w'(t)=-2w(t).$ Find the *simplest* solution.

The must general solution is to have $y(t)$ be any function with $y(0)=1$ and $w(t)$ be any function with $w'(t)=-2w(t).$ By the reasonable criterion I suggested, $y(t)=1$ and $w(t)=0$ is indeed simplest.

BUT I might leave out $w(t)$ and say "How simple can $z(t)$ be? What about $z(t)=0?$ That forces $y(t)=e^{-2t}.$"